# How do i set a specific cooldown error message for a specific command

Tags: python, discord

I am trying to make a economy bot and I have a 1h cooldown on work command and cooldown on some other commands too. Then I wrote the event -

```py
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx,error):
    if isinstance(error,commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        await ctx.send(f'You have already worked, try again in {round(error.retry_after, 2)}')
```

But it shows the same message for every cooldown error. I want it to be specific on which command the cooldown is and I also want to convert the cooldown timer from seconds to other units (hr/min)

Answer (score 0):

The [`ctx`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context) object should have lots of information you can use to work out what command it was and then do specific things with it.

There's the `cog` parameter which returns the Cog (if you're using Cogs) or there's the `invoked_with` attribute for getting the command alias. Or, you can use the [`command`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Command.name) attribute to return the `Command` and get the name from there. There's quite a few different parameters you could use so it might be worth looking through and finding something that fits your use case.

But for example:

```py
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        if ctx.command.name == "some_cool_command":
            # send error message to do with that command
            error_message = ""
        elif ctx.command.name == "some_other_command":
            # send error message to do with this command
            error_message = ""
        else:
            # have a default error message for those that don't fit the critera
            error_message = ""
        await ctx.send(error_message)
```

This is of course assuming you're using `discord.py` and not another library.

Comment: thnx ! this helped a lot.